# nth degree representing in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
  matrix_add([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]).
```

I expected result is

```
 matrix A is [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]
 matrix B is [1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]
 sum is [1,0,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,2]
```

And this one is possible in nth degree.

For example `matrix_add([[0,1],[2,3]],[[2,1],[6,4]]).` is possible.

```
 matrix_add([],[],[]).
 matrix_add(M1,M2,Result):-

        nl,
        write('matrix A is'),
        nl,
        writeln(M1),
```

// but it didn't work.

```
        nl,
        write('matrix B is'),
        nl,
        writeln(M2),
        Result is (M1 + M2),
        nl,

        nl,
        write('sum is'),
        nl,
        writeln(Result).
```

Would u tell me how to show this array of array?

===================================================

```
  matrix_add([M1|M1s],[M2|M2s]):-
       write('==============='),
       nl,
       write('Matrix A is'),
       nl,
       write(M1),
       write(M1s),
       nl,
       write('==============='),
       nl,
       write('Matrix B is'),
       nl,
       write(M2),
       writeln(M2s),
       nl,
       matrix_add_aux(M1,M2,[R|Rs]),
       write('==============='),
       nl,
       write('Sum is'),
       nl,
       writeln(R),
       writeln(Rs).
```

i want the result is like this.

```
  matrix A is 
  [0,0,1]
  [0,1,1]
  [1,1,1]
  ...
```

Comment: Can you show some attempt at solving the problem? You only need to break it down into a couple of layers of standard list processing.

Comment: matrix_add([A|B],C):-
 matrix_add(A,[A|B],C).
matrix_add(Cs,Ps):-
 nl,
 write('matrix 1 is'),
 nl,
 writeln(Cs),
 writeln(Ps), .....

Comment: That's not much and would be incorrect even to add two "null" matrices. That has the two operands, but no result. If you want to say in Prolog, *The empty matrix plus the empty matrix is the empty matrix*, that would be, `matrix_add([], [], []).`. And the general predicate would look like, `matrix_add(M1, M2, Result)` so that the predicate can provide a result. Is this homework for a class?

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment. Could u tell me function of writeln? I don't know represent matrix A by doubly linked list.

Comment: I Prolog you don't use a "linked list" but what you already show, for example, `M1` might be, `[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]`. A matrix is an "array of arrays" (or in Prolog, representing an "array" as a list, which is an ordered sequence of elements). You process a list one element at a time in Prolog, using the form, `[H|T]` where `H` is the first element of the list, and `T` is the rest of the list. So your predicate needs to look at each array in the matrix in turn and add the arrays together to make the array for the result. The result is an array of those arrays (a matrix).

Comment: So, could u tell me how to display an array of those arrays?? And how can i express result value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guillermo's answer is correct, but here is more of an explanation as to the process of getting there.

There's a very short way of doing this using the built-in `maplist`. But for the sake of learning how to process lists in Prolog, being that this is an assignment, here are some tips on how to approach the problem.

A 2-dimensional matrix is a 1-dimensional array (or vector) of 1-dimensional arrays (or vectors). An array is an ordered sequence of values, which is exactly what a list is in Prolog. So an array is conveniently represented by a list. As shown in your example input matrices:

First matrix: `[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]`

In this matrix, the first row is `[0,0,1]`, second is `[0,1,1]`, and the third is `[1,1,1]`.

To add two matrices, you go through each row as an array and you add the arrays together. How do you add two arrays? Same process: you go through each element and add the elements together. So you know your solution is going to look like that.

And you know (hopefully) in Prolog that the form `[H|T]` represents a list and gives you the first element of the list, `H`, and the rest of the list `T`. For example, if you have:

```
[H|T] = [[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

Then `H = [0,0,1]` and `T = [[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]`.

To solve your problem, first, write out the solution in plain language so you know what you're doing. :)

*The empty matrix plus the empty matrix is the empty matrix.*

```
matrix_add([], [], []).
```

Now refer back to what was said above about how to add two matrices, and think of the matrices as a list of lists with a head and a tail:

*The sum of matrices `[H1|T1]` and `[H2|T2]` is `[H|T]` if the sum of the vectors `H1` and `H2` is `H` and the sum of matrices `T1` and `T2` is `T`.*

```
matrix_add([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H|T]) :-
    vector_add(H1, H2, H),
    matrix_add(T1, T2, T).
```

That completes the `matrix_add` predicate. You now have to write `vector_add`. The `vector_add` predicate will look just like the `matrix_add`, except each element in a vector is just a number, not a list, so you can just add them and be done.

When you run your query:

```
matrix_add([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]], Result).
```

Prolog will display the answer for you:

```
Result = [[1,0,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

You can do the displaying using `writeln`, but this is the more common way to do it in Prolog since it provides the result in an argument rather than just writing it to the display. If you want to write it to the display, you can always put the `writeln([H1|T1])` or whatever in the code.

---

**EPILOGUE**

Here's the abbreviated solution using `maplist`:

```
matrix_add(M1, M2, Result) :-
    writeln('Matrix A is'),
    write_matrix(M1),
    writeln('Matrix B is'),
    write_matrix(M2),
    maplist(maplist(add), M1, M2, Result),
    writeln('Matrix A+B is'),
    write_matrix(Result).

write_matrix(M) :-
    maplist(writeln, M), nl.

add(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.
```

With result:

```
?- matrix_add([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]], Result).
Matrix A is
[0,0,1]
[0,1,1]
[1,1,1]

Matrix B is
[1,0,0]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,1]

Matrix A+B is
[1,0,1]
[1,2,1]
[2,2,2]

Result = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]].
```

Comment: So, how to show this one? like 'matrix A is [0,0,1], nl,[0,1,1],nl , [1,1,1].'

Comment: @user3450300 the way you show it is correct in your code example. And Guillermo has a good use of it in his correct answer. You just use `write` or `writeln` and `nl` where you need for new lines. For example, `write('matrix A is '), write([H1|T1]), nl.`

Comment: I write additional question, Could you tell me? ============ after is question.

Comment: @user3450300 create a predicate called `write_matrix([]). write_matrix([H|T]) :- writeln(H), write_matrix(T).` And call it on whatever matrix you want to write. This is very simple list processing and if you are learning your Prolog list processing, should be simple for you to figure out if you think about it long enough.

Answer (score 1):

This matches what you attempt:

```
%initial call
matrix_add(M1,M2):-
    write('Matrix A is'),
    writeln(M1),
    write('Matrix B is'),
    writeln(M2),
    matrix_add_aux(M1,M2,Result),
    write('Sum is'),
    writeln(Result).

%now check rows one by one

%base case
matrix_add_aux([],[],[]).

%recursive case
matrix_add_aux([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[R|Rs]):-
    matrix_add_row(X,Y,R),
    matrix_add_aux(Xs,Ys,Rs).

%and now sum the values in the row

%base case
matrix_add_row([],[],[]).

%recursive case
matrix_add_row([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[R|Rs]):-
    R is X + Y,
    matrix_add_row(Xs,Ys,Rs).
```

Comment: This is a correct answer (+1). I've continued with my answer to help explain the process.